# Operations in php variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code;

```
$sel_referrals1="SELECT SUM(amount) as da_sum 
  FROM topup WHERE user_id IN ( SELECT t1.referree
  FROM referrals AS t1
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t2 ON t2.referrer = t1.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t3 ON t3.referrer = t2.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t4 ON t4.referrer = t3.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t5 ON t5.referrer = t4.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t6 ON t6.referrer = t5.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t7 ON t7.referrer = t6.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t8 ON t8.referrer = t7.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t9 ON t9.referrer = t8.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t10 ON t10.referrer = t9.referree
  LEFT JOIN referrals AS t11 ON t11.referrer = t10.referree
WHERE t1.referrer = '{$_SESSION['user']}')
AND YEAR(date_time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
AND MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())";        

$selected1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel_referrals1);
$sel_level1_array=mysqli_fetch_row($selected1);
$level1=number_format($sel_level1_array[0],2);

$curYear = date('Y');
$curMonth = date('F');
$rate1 = 0.02;
$rate2 = 0.008;
$rate3 = 0.004;
$level11 = 1260.00;
$total=$level1 * $rate1;

echo $total;
```

`$level1` returns **1260.00**
I have another variable `$rate1` which i declared as `$rate1=0.02`
I need to multiply `$level1` with `$rate1`. When I do `$level1*$rate1` I get **0.02**,

My expected result is **25.02**. What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: I tried with `$level1 = 1260.00;
$rate1  = 0.02;
echo $level1*$rate1;` and the result is `25.2`. it seems working fine to me.

Comment: Last time you showed the code with `echo $level1*$rate1` why don't you compose a question showing *all* of the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**number_format** returns a string

```
$level1=number_format($sel_level1_array[0],2);
```

Use **floatval**

```
$level1 = floatval($sel_level1_array[0]);
```